# Why is this html isn't printed by scala?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'am trying to create a sitemap with Play Framework. For that I need a while loop which runs till a specfic `Long` value is reached. The loop actually works but the html inside isn't printed altough the `println()` works fine (output is printed on the console)

```
    @{
    var i = 0L
    var amountOfSitemaps = 10L;
    while(i < amountOfSitemaps) {
        <url>
            <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
            <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
            <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
            <priority>0.8</priority>
        </url>
        println("why is the stuff above not printed?!")
        i+=1
    }}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: och totally bad approach... have you got a List of Sites passed from controller?

Comment: @biesior yes, but with this code I'am trying to create a "Sitemap index" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap_index ). This is based on a ´çount´ of all URLs in the database, which is a ´Long´ value. I could actually cast it to an ´int´, but ... urm... I'am stubborn :) So is there a way to get the code above to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest solution for your sample is:

```
@for(item <- 0 until 10) {
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
}
```

In real sitemap it would be something like:

```
@(listOfSites: List[Site])

@for(site <- listOfSites) {
    <url>
        <loc>@site.url</loc>
        <lastmod>@site.lastMod</lastmod>
        <changefreq>@site.changeFreq</changefreq>
        <priority>@site.priority</priority>
    </url>
}
```

Assuming that you pass a

check the difference between `@for(item <- 0 until 10)` and `@for(item <- 0 to 10)`

Comment: The problem was somehow caused by the while loop inside the @{} part. Somehow the templating engine has a problem with double curly braces. I don't know.. I'am totally new to scala.
Anyway.. with the for loop I don't that extra pair of curly braces and it also works with a ´Long´ value. 
Thank you very much!